# Android Horizontal Scroll View for showing youtube vidoes

Tags: android, youtube

am creating android application which will displays youtube videos on horizontal(Landscape) list view similar to application in screen-shot. And when i click on one of the video then it should play, which is what currently happening, am able to load all the youtube videos along with there thumbnails in simple list view(Vertical) in android, but i couldn't found out a way so far, using which I can show all videos in the youtube playlist in the manner as shown in the following screen shot layout view.
If any one knows how I could show my video list in horizontal(Landscape) layout as depicted in the attached screen-shot, it would be great help for me.

Please visit link to see the screenshot: https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/954e89ab4d5fef83bb19009107d71c60.png

Thank You.

Here Sample code

Sorry for the Logs, as am running it on device.

MainActivity

```
    package in.wptrafficanalyzer.viewpagerdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Getting a reference to the ViewPager defined the layout file */        
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        /** Getting fragment manager */
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        /** Instantiating FragmentPagerAdapter */
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

        /** Setting the pagerAdapter to the pager object */
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.viewpagerdemo;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

    int mCurrentPage;
    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBaoObw6vr4uCJnCXXXXXXXX";

    //http://youtu.be/<VIDEO_ID>
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "dKLftgvYsVU";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
        Bundle data = getArguments();

        /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
        mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container,false);             
        YouTubePlayerView tv = (YouTubePlayerView ) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        tv.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        return v;       
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

        /** Start buffering **/
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
        }

    };

    private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
    };
}
```

MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.viewpagerdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;

    /** Constructor of the class */
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
        myFragment.setArguments(data);
        return myFragment;
    }

    /** Returns the number of pages */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {     
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {        
        return "Page #" + ( position + 1 );
    }




}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

myfragment_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.viewpagerdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you tried view pager?

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, can you just point me to some example.

Comment: see this:http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/,http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: am unable to load the given URL, can you just give some other example.

Comment: See http:/developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html , http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/

Comment: I tried with code similar to one you mentioned here http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/ but my sample code uses textview instead of imageview, so i just replace the textview in the code with YouTubePlayerView which will play the youtube video, but when i run the code the app crashes can you just tell me where am doing mistake, I used the same code as you posted previously.

Comment: can you post your code and logcat

Comment: I posted the code can you please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Your my Fragment Xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        />
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now code accordingly and Post your logcat for crash issue resolution.

Comment: can you tell me where, in other files i need to make the changes, coz it's still crashing.